# Как создавать кластер в Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Недавно начал изучать k8s и в процессе возник вопрос.

Каким образом создавать сам кластер? Ноды на серверах? Везде пишут про облачные сервера или миникуб(как я понял, у него только одна нода), а я хочу запустить на своих серверах. Или как раз таки устанавливаем миникуб на все сервера и обозначаем, кто является мастером, а кто воркером?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @Kromster, исправил

Comment: Еще название вопроса стоит сделать более соответствующим телу вопроса

Comment: @Kromster, а Вы можете мне помочь?

Comment: Так я вам уже помогаю, точнее и правильнее сформулировать вопрос, чтобы на него было проще дать ответ

Comment: @Kromster, Я понял) Спасибо!)))

Answer (score 0):

Установить можешь через kubeadm подробно расписано в [документации](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) или если знаком с ansible через [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
Не чего не сказано про цели установки и что за сервера (Baremetal\VM\other).

Чтобы на учиться и попрактиковаться подними 2 VM, собери на них свой первый кластер и удалишь по окончанию, в место того чтобы перезаливать Baremetal